# Posting some dynamic data with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this html page

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-lg-2">School Location</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="text" name="sl" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="School Location" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-lg-2">School Logo</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="file" name="ls" id="ls" class="schoollogo form-control" value="" placeholder="School Location" required>
</div>
</div>
```

with one text input and one file input. Once i select a file,the file is being uploaded and i am getting back the uploaded file link

```
'change .schoollogo': function(event, template) {

    FS.Utility.eachFile(event,function(file){

        var fileObj=new FS.File(file);

        Uploads.insert(fileObj,function(err){

            var lspath = fileObj.url({brokenIsFine: true});
            var au = Meteor.absoluteUrl();
            $("#ls").val(lspath);

        });

        })

  }
```

Once,i have got the file,i am submitting the data like this

```
'submit .school': function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      var sn = event.target.sn.value;
      var sd = event.target.sd.value;
      var sl = event.target.sl.value;
      var ls = event.target.ls.value;

      var sn = sn.replace(/\s/g, '');

      var post = {
    input_sn: sn,
    input_sd: sd,
    input_sl: sl,
    input_ls: ls
    };
    var schoolexists = Schools.find({schoolname: sn}, {limit: 1}).count() > 0;
    if(schoolexists == true){
        alert('school already exists');
    }
    if(schoolexists == false){

    Meteor.call('schoolNew', post);
    return false;
    }
    }
```

The problem is,my code is not setting the value of the uploaded link

```
$("#ls").val(lspath);
```

like in the code above.  How can i set the file path such that,its posted to the server on submit. Currently,the code only picks the file name of the file selected and not the path as i would like.

`lspath` contains the upload image path,this i have confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use local storage.Inside my submit code,i retrieve the set value

```
var ls = localStorage.getItem("fp");
```

which i had earlier set like

```
'change .schoollogo': function(event, template) {

    FS.Utility.eachFile(event,function(file){

        var fileObj=new FS.File(file);

        Uploads.insert(fileObj,function(err){

            var lspath = fileObj.url({brokenIsFine: true});
            var au = Meteor.absoluteUrl();
            localStorage.setItem("fp", lspath);

        });

        })

  }
```